# How to batch insert to two tables using anorm with foreign key

Tags: sql, scala, playframework-2.3, anorm

Im having trouble doing this batch operations like this.

```
val params = Seq(Seq[NamedParameter]("valueA" -> 1, "valueB" -> 2))

BatchSql(SQL(
  """
     INSERT INTO tableA ( valueA ) VALUES ( {valueA} );
     INSERT INTO tableB ( tableAId, valueB ) VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID(), {valueB});
  """.stripMargin), params).execute()
```

With tables like...

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  valueA int
); 

CREATE TABLE tableB
(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  tableAId int,
  valueA int,
  FOREIGN KEY (tableAId) REFERENCES tableA (id),
);
```

I get this exception, just complaining about line 2.

```
BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO tableB  ( tableAid, valueA' at line 1]]
```

Thanks

Comment: As JDBC prepared statement is used, only one SQL statement is expected. So the second statement in the SQL string is in this way a syntax error. Batch update (with Anorm or with direct JDBC) is about executing a list of list of paramaters (batch parameters) with the same single statement (prepared for each list of parameter in the batch). So I would say such JDBC batch update should be impossible whatever is your JDBC driver (underlying DB).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Maybe this is where stored procedures are useful.

Comment: FYI Anorm works fine with stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You need two tables, the first generates the primary key, the second uses the newly created primary key as foreign key ..

```
create table TABLE_1 columns ID_TABLE_1 PK, A, B (UNIC), C;
create table TABLE_2 columns ID_TABLE_1 FK, D, E;

DECLARE @unicValue int = 987;
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (A,B,C) VALUES ('A', @unicValue, 'C');

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (ID_TABLE_1, D, E) VALUES (
 (SELECT ID_TABLE_1 FROM TABLE_1 WHERE B = @unicValue), 'VALUE', 'C');
```

- Add multiple "batch"..
- Execute batch !